# ajax and javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, forms

I've used ajax (in a most simple way that any basic tutorial shows) to change my main div on a web page so that when I click on a different field in my navigation bar, a different data or a form is displayed in a same div.

Now, there is obviously a problem with my understanding of ajax because when I try to do most simple form validation with javascript on elements that are loaded to my page with ajax, it doesn't work. For example, a check box (unchecked) and a submit button is loaded with ajax. When I check the box and click the submit button just to see if check box is checked, I get nothing, or I get that it isn't checked.

I've tried the same example (checkbox+submit) without ajax and it works just fine.

Is there any logic that I've missed in this situation?

Thanks!

Edit: sorry for not posting code. 
Here it is. My ajax code:

```
function loadWholePage(url)
{
    var y = document.getElementById("storage");
    //var x = document.getElementById("displayed");
    var x = document.getElementById("content");
    loadHTML(url, processHTML, x, y);
}   

function loadHTML(url, fun, storage, param)
    {
var xhr = createXHR();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
{ 
    if(xhr.readyState == 4) //  The request is complete
    {
        //if(xhr.status == 200)
        {
            storage.innerHTML = getBody(xhr.responseText);

            fun( storage, param );
        }
    } 
}; 


xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send(null); 
    } 

function getBody(content) 
{
 test = content.toLowerCase();    // to eliminate case sensitivity
 var x = test.indexOf("<body");
 if(x == -1) return "";

 x = test.indexOf(">", x);
 if(x == -1) return "";

 var y = test.lastIndexOf("</body>");
 if(y == -1) y = test.lastIndexOf("</html>");
 if(y == -1) y = content.length;    // If no HTML then just grab everything till end

 return content.slice(x + 1, y);   
}
```

Html file I load with ajax:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="values" value="" id="chk3" />
<select name="select3" class="test" style="width:7em;" id="select3">
<option VALUE="">0-100</option>
<option VALUE="/tags/">100-200</option>
<option VALUE="/"> 200-300</option>
<option VALUE="/"> 300-400</option>
<option VALUE="/"> 400-500</option>
</select>
<input type="button" class="submit" id="testbutton" style="width:12em;" value="submit" onClick="testIt();">
 </form>                            
 </body>
</html>
```

I load it using:

```
<li onClick='setSelectedListElement(this);'>
<a onclick="loadWholePage('test.html');">TEST
</a>
</li>
```

And the really primitive  script that should check if check box is checked :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testIt(){
var x=document.getElementById("chk3").checked;
alert(x);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Without code, who knows, but could have to do with: elements being added improperly (not being recognized by the DOM), using jQuery selectors that ran BEFORE the new content was added and not reflecting the updated DOM...

Comment: I edited my original post, hope that's not a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once your page is loaded, Right Click-> View Source and check the Ids of your controls that are generated at runtime.
Try to use those Ids of the controls (checkboxes etcs) and check if the validations are triggered or not.